# How to change the default Laravel Eloquent table-id-name

Tags: laravel, eloquent, default, factory

When i create a Laravel Factory like this:

```
factory(App\User::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($user) {

    $user->useroptions()->save(factory(App\UserOption::class)->make(['user_id' => $user->id]));

});
```

, Laravel will require the `user_id` as a part of the useroption-table, because the origin table is `user` and the required value is `id` - ùser_id`.

Now, when i want to use `uid` instead of `user_id`, what should i do?

Comment: you need to define the custom primary id while defining the relationship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the foreign key the relationship uses like so

```php
public function useroptions() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserOption', 'uid');
}
```